# Invalid Conversion from item type: LIST error

Tags: google-apps-script

EDIT: Code updated based on @Tanaike's suggetsion. It now submits, but not populating the 1st and 2nd dropdown list in form with values from 1st and 2nd column from table.

I have a google form with 4 questions. First and second questions are drop-downs. Third is free-text (this wont need to get values from google sheet) and 4th is a date field that doesn't need to get brought in either.

I want to get values from a google sheet that I specified in script to pre-populate:

```
    function openForm() {
      var form = findFormByName('Comment Updates');
      if (form) {
        populateQuestions(form);
      } else {
        Logger.log('Form not found');
      }
    }

    function findFormByName(formName) {
      var form = FormApp.openById('1GPYQHsDFIPMI4ny2qrDcp8PUUZdhGvfkd7Uyc5-Rk0Q');
      var title = form.getTitle();
      if (title === formName) {
        return form;
      }
      return null; // Return null if form is not found
    }

    function populateQuestions(form) {
      var googleSheetsQuestions = getQuestionValues();
      var itemsArray = form.getItems();
      itemsArray.forEach(function(item, index) {
        if (index == 0 || index == 1) { // Dropdown questions
          var choiceArray = googleSheetsQuestions[index + 1].filter(function(choice) {
            return choice != '';
          });
          // Convert each choice to string and remove empty values
          var choiceValues = choiceArray.filter(function(choice) {
            return choice != '';
          });
        item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(choiceValues);
        } else if (index == 3) { // Date question
          item.asDateItem();
        }
      });
    }

    function getQuestionValues() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('13o5d1AhslmYP3BcO1U16DxkyoCxo44rt7wgOKcq-PeE');
      var questionSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Data for Form');
      var returnData = questionSheet.getRange(2, 1, questionSheet.getLastRow() - 1, questionSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
      return returnData;
    }
```

Table in google sheets (column A should be in a dropdown in 1st form question)

[image]

Seems to be that the form populates 1 row 4 columns as 4 choices for each question.

[image]

Comment: @Cooper I mean I'm not trying to learn js when the only time I'll ever need to learn it is this one single instance. I'l start from scratch

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your actual Google Form, I proposed a modification point from your showing script and error message. Please confirm it. If my guess was not correct, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your showing script and error message `Error Exception: Invalid conversion item type: LIST`, I guessed that the reason for your current issue might be due to `item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(choiceValues);`. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(choiceValues);
```

#### To:

```
item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(choiceValues);
```

Or, if your Google Form includes MultipleChoiceItem, how about the following modification?

```
var type = item.getType();
if (type == FormApp.ItemType.LIST) {
  item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(choiceValues);
} else if (type == FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE) {
  item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(choiceValues);
}
```

#### Note:

- From your error message, it supposes that other parts of your script work. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [asListItem()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#aslistitem)
- [asMultipleChoiceItem()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item#asmultiplechoiceitem)

Comment: Hey @Tanaike I really apprecaite your help. So the form submitted, but it seems to be submitting each row in the table (4 columns) as a 4 list option per the first 2 questions. I'm going to edit my post with two images to show you

Comment: I have updated what is going on. It submits now (thank you!) but it seems to be taking an offset of +2 from header and transposing the row into a choice option format instead of a dropdown with all of those ID's in column A and Products in column B in sheet

Comment: @NidenK Thank you for replying. I was surprised that your question has been changed. First, I would like to confirm your question. You want to remove the error message of `Error Exception: Invalid conversion item type: LIST`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: You did correct that, I'll repost my question with new roadblock im facing. thanks again

Comment: @NidenK Thank you for replying. I understand your reply. In your current situation, the error of `Error Exception: Invalid conversion item type: LIST` was resolved. But, another issue occurred. Is my understanding correct? I would like to have confirmed your current situation first. Because if your issue is still not resolved, it is required to modify my answer. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: @NidenK Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your new issue, how about modifying `return returnData;` to `return returnData[0].map((_, col) => returnData.map((row) => row[col] || null));` at the function `getQuestionValues`? And also, how about modifying `var choiceArray = googleSheetsQuestions[index + 1].filter(function(choice) {` to `var choiceArray = googleSheetsQuestions[index].filter(function (choice) {` at the function `populateQuestions`? If I misunderstood your new issue, I apologize.